# Validation of UTF-8 bytes array in C#

Tags: c#, utf-8

A few months ago I found interesting scripts that validate utf-8 bytes array

So now I'm refactoring my code and I forgot what this code do.

```cs
    public void ValidateUTF8Bytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        int charCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetCharCount(bytes);
        char[] chars = new char[charCount];
        int charsDecodedCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, chars, 0);
        
        if (charsDecodedCount != charCount)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

So how it works:

1. Convert (I think under the hood) bytes array into chars array and return length of chars array
2. introduce chars variable (what for??)
3. Again convert bytes array into variable chars and return length of this array

So 1) and 3) do the same specifically in this block of code, not?

p.s. What type of exception should I throw and what text of exception should be?

Comment: Its a good pattern of work comment your code

Comment: This doesn't validate much, it just counts the characters and then creates it as an array of that size. I doubt `if (charsDecodedCount != charCount)` would ever be true

Comment: Since `GetCharCount`  and `GetChars` without validation both ignore invalid sequences, then yeah, `charsDecodedCount` will always equal `charCount`. It's not like `GetCharCount` is "get the number of characters while also somehow counting things that aren't characters".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to validate arbitrary data to ensure it really contains valid UTF-8 text, the best way is to let the framework handle the validation. However, the encoding object you get from the static `Encoding.UTF8` property has validation disabled. Without validation, invalid sequences are simply ignored.

To enable it, you have to create an `UTF8Encoding` object, and then use it:

```
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, true); // <-- true for validation
var text = encoding.GetString(bytes);
```

The above call to `GetString` will raise an `ArgumentException` if invalid sequences are found in the data.

Comment: For just validation `GetCharCount` might be more efficient as no copying done.